# content not showing in text area?

Tags: textarea

I have a textarea and for some reason when I try to add text in between the open and close brackets of my textarea it wont display, whether I use html content or php echoed content.

It works if I place the content in a place holder though, does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<form action="includes/changebio.php" method="post" id="form1">         
 <textarea id="bio" style="width: 440px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 120px;
    resize: none; 
    outline:none;
    overflow:scroll;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;"
    textarea name="bio" data-id="bio" 
    maxlength="710" 
    placeholder="<?php echo stripslashes($profile['bio']); ?>" rows="10">
 </textarea>
<input type="image" src="assets/img/icons/save-edit.png"
       class="bio-submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried your code on my windows machine and I had no problem.

Comment: its currently set as a placeholder though, if u take the content out of the place holder and place it between <textarea>..</textarea> it doesnt show for me

Comment: Make sure your `$profile['bio']` is not empty.

Comment: it does it even if i replace $profile['bio'] with html and still wont display

Answer (score 9):

Try adding a `name="textarea-name"`attribute to the textarea (even if you have no use for it)

**Edit**:

I have tested a `<textarea name="bio">textarea content</textarea>` piece of code and concluded that (as strange as it may seem), if the textarea name is `bio`, the content is no shown in Firefox, although it is present if the element is inspected with Firebug or a similar tool.

It appears to be something caused by one of my add-ons, as the textarea content it is displayed correctly by other browsers and when using a clean new Firefox profile.

I have not investigated further though.

Comment: Super! How is it but?!! can You please explain?

Comment: this happens to me too, glad i come across your answer

Answer (score 5):

Simplest method that worked for me:

**Instead of doing:-**

```
<textarea name="scenario" value="<?php echo $scenario?>"> </textarea>
```

**Do it like this:-**

```
<textarea name="scenario"> <?php echo $scenario?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem! When I change the content with ajax, Chrome & Firefox displayed nothing, but IE displayed correctly. What strange is the content is present if the element is inspected with Firebug or a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `textarea` after style tag. Here is the code.

```
<form action="includes/changebio.php" method="post" id="form1">         
<textarea id="bio" style="width: 440px; 
 margin-top:3px;
 text-align:left;
 margin-left:-2px;
 height: 120px;
 resize: none; 
 outline:none;
 overflow:scroll;
 border: #ccc 1px solid;" name="bio" data-id="bio" maxlength="710"
placeholder="<?php   echo stripslashes($profile['bio']); ?>" rows="10"><?php echo stripslashes($profile['bio']); ?></textarea>
<input type="image" src="assets/img/icons/save-edit.png"class="bio-submit" name="submit"  value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem and resolved it by doing **like this**:

{{\App\ArtObject::find($id)->description}}

Earlier I had:
description}}">

The later case did **NOT** show the value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is same as mine, where I placed a string variable with 1500 chars for a web content, between the two  tags, and only partial appeared inside the Textarea on the page. Only about 900 chars displayed. A large part at the end were missing. Then, you may try what worked for me, where I used the htmlspecialchars() function like this:

```
<TEXTAREA><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pgCont); ?></TEXTAREA>
```

I still don't know why this function may be required to show the full contents of the string variable. Perhaps, for security reasons.